# Guide for writing new Openstack module/project

Tags: openstack

We're currently deploying an openstack private cloud and I've been asked to write some additional functionality for it. I've used openstack before, but never written part of it. I've taken a look at the code for some of the components (trove, for example) but so far I haven't found any guides to writing your own component/project (whatever the terminology is).

We need it to integrate with keystone for identity but apart from that it is fairly standalone. Ideally it would be written in python as then it can borrow code from other openstack projects and hopefully eventually be opensourced.

Are there any good guides/tutorials for writing your own openstack component available? What's the best IDE for development - is it pydev?

Answer (score 1):

There are no guides and tutorials for writing your own openstack component. But I would suggest you use the openstack mailing list in case some one has documented anything they have developed.

Another advice is to gain understanding of the existing openstack components. You can see the developer guides, api guides and admin guide. They are all available at docs.openstack.org

IDE should not be an issue at all. you can use whatever you are comfortable with.

Sticking to python good.